# trying to setup cntlm on ubuntu for NTLM authentication

Tags: squid

I am trying to setup cntlm on ubuntu13 for NTLM authentication.  I used apt-get install to setup ctlm.  My cntlm.conf file in the etc directory is copied below - the username/domain and password are correct (I have tested them with a different application).

**cntlm.conf**

```
    # Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration

    Username        account
    Domain          xxxxxx.com
    Password        password

    # Workstation   netbios_hostname

   Proxy                xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128
    ###Proxy                10.0.0.42:8080

    NoProxy         localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, 0.0.*

    Listen          3128

    #SOCKS5Proxy    8010
    #SOCKS5User     dave:password

    #Auth           NTLM2
    #Flags          0x06820000

    #Gateway        yes

    #Allow          127.0.0.1
    #Deny           0/0

    #ISAScannerSize     1024
    #ISAScannerAgent    Wget/
    #ISAScannerAgent    APT-HTTP/
    #ISAScannerAgent    Yum/

    #Header         User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)
    #Tunnel         11443:remote.com:443
```

**Error Message in /var/log/syslog:**

```
Proxy returning invalid challenge!
```

cntlm is running on port 3129 (squid running on port 3128).  I pointed IE to use the proxy on the IP address and port number for cntlm (I tried with squid as well) - however, the connection times out.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your firewall is disallowing this connection. You can confirm by temporarily disabling it.

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

To allow these ports access:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3128/tcp
$ sudo ufs allow 3129/tcp
```

You can also see what's open using `status`:

```
$ sudo ufw status

Firewall loaded

To                         Action  From
--                         ------  ----
22:tcp                     DENY    192.168.0.1
22:udp                     DENY    192.168.0.1
22:tcp                     DENY    192.168.0.7
22:udp                     DENY    192.168.0.7
22:tcp                     ALLOW   192.168.0.0/24
22:udp                     ALLOW   192.168.0.0/24
```

If it's disabled:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

#### References

- [UFW - Ubuntu's firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Comment: thanks though I am not certain that's the issue - I have not enabled ip tables/ufw on this VM.  cntlm and squid are able to listen on ports 3129 and 3128 - squid works with basic auth for me.  I am trying to get cntlm to work with squid to test NTLM auth.  I have tried adding squid port as parent proxy in the cntlm conf file (even tried tinyproxy) - I just see the connection dropped/reset by the AD server (I checked network packets for troubleshooting this issue) - its possible that AD might have firewall rules but I am able to authenticate against AD from a different VM using a separate appl.